# Stanford C++ coursework. Gauss' childhood

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Here I am doing Standford C++ coursework.

Exercise 03 from reader exercises. Here is the given question:

> Exercise 03  Compute the sum of the numbers between 1 and 100.
>
> ```
> /*
>     As mathematical historians have told the story, the German mathematician
>     Karl Friedrich Gauss (1777-1855) began to show his mathematical talent 
>     at a very early age. When he was in elementary school, Gauss was asked by
>     his teacher to compute the sum of the numbers between 1 and 100. Gauss is
>     said to have given the answer instantly: 5050. Write a program that computes
>     the answer to the question Gauss’s teacher posed.
>  */
> ```

The error I am getting when executing this program is this => Guassian.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Guassian.cpp:29:12: error: invalid use of non-static member function
 ob1.sumodds;

What's wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Guassian
{


public:

int sumodds ( int  last )
{
    int result =    0;
    int odd = 1;
    for ( int i =    0; i < last; i++ ) 
    {
        result +=   odd;
        odd += 2;
    }
    return            result ;

}

};

int main()
{
Guassian ob1;
ob1.sumodds;
//return 0;
}
```

Comment: well......try to give your function a value might help

Comment: `ob1.sumodds;` is a member function and requires to be called as `ob1.sumodds(last);`, whatever `last` should be.

Comment: Are you programming in C++ or are you Java programming in C++?  The C++ language allows *free standing* functions.  You don't need to put everything in a class.  For example, the `main` is a free standing function.

Answer (score 2):

Karl Friedrich Gauss probably did not compute it the way you did. Furthermore the correct answer to the problem would be

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int n)
{
  return n*(n+1)/2;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << sum(100) << '\n';
}
```

If you would use your function in a similar way I did, you would actually calculate the sum of `last`-many odd numbers. See [here](https://ideone.com/lxfhOq).

I am not sure if you want this.

Comment: Actually in the coursework PDF file they had posted this and the function was given by them. I merely wrote the public and private part and did the object calling. Thought I had to figure out whats wrong with the code and make it right.

Comment: You made the function call wrong. Do you see the example in the link I posted? Why do you want to wrap it in a class?

Comment: Yes I saw the ideone example you provided. I am wrapping it in a class because I am trying to learn OOPS and I think even the simplest of the simple programs in C++ must be done using class + object thing. Is this the right way to think?

Comment: Yes. Then look into the comments of your question to learn how to call class methods.

Comment: The formula you have posted above is correct. But now I have come to think whats wrong with the question then? I have posted the question too above, as it is from the courseware folder.

Comment: Gauss probably thought about it something along these lines. The question is identical to summing the numbers from 0 to 100. Sum 0 and 100, then 1 and 99, etc. noting that each sum is exactly 100. The 50th term would be the sum of 49 and 51 yielding a total of 5000. The number 50 is the only one missing so the adding it to the total yields 5050.  Might be useful to write a program that also does it the way Gauss likely did.